# Collision among kinematic-dynamic-static body that hangs simulation (2d)

Tags: libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I really appreciate if any of you can help me with this issue in my game or give an advice.

I have a kinematic body moving upwards (my camera is always following this body) and many static bodies scattered on the level-screen (I'm developing a Top-Down game).

Then, I have a character, which is a dynamic body, moving around by the player (using touch events). This character can collide with this kinematic body and with the static bodies.

My problems is, when the main character get stuck between both (kinematic and static -like a sandwich-) the physics simulation hangs! (in Android and in the desktop version).

How can I detect this behavior and what can I do to prevent it?
I'm using libgdx, box2d with a contactListener to detect collisions.

Thanks

libgdx version: 1.9.8

Comment: Do you happen to know what version of libgdx or box2d you're using? If so, please update your question with that info. Also, when you say "hang", do you mean that the world step call isn't even returning? I can imagine some of the older Box2D code hanging that way but the later code is more likely just going to get slower I'd think.

Comment: hi, I'm using libgdx version: 1.9.8 and you're right, when I said "hang" I meant to say that the simulation becomes extremely slow.